# Excel - Lookup the group based on value range per segment

Tags: excel

I have a table like below.

```
segmentnum  group 1 group 2 group 3 group 4
1           0       12      33      66
2           0       3       10      26
3           0       422     1433    3330
```

And a table like below.

```
vol     segmentnum  
0       1           
58      1           
66      1           
48      1           
9       2           
13      2           
7       2           
10      3           
1500    3
```

I'd like to add a column that tells me which group the vol for a given segmentnum belongs to. Such that

```
Group 1 = x to < group 2
Group 2 = x to < group 3
Group 3 = x to <= group 4
```

Desired result:

```
vol     segmentnum  group
0       1           1
58      1           3
66      1           3
48      1           3
9       2           2
13      2           3
7       2           2
10      3           3
1500    3           3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the accompanying image, put this in I2 and drag down.

```
=MATCH(G2, INDEX(B$2:E$4, MATCH(H2, A$2:A$4, 0), 0))
```

[image]

While these results differ from yours, I believe they are correct.

Comment: Thanks for this! I made a mistake in the desired result. Apologies for that. I've made the changes above. In any case, this is close but not quite. It doesn't seem to take into account the less than condition. There would ideally be only 3 groups (e.g. for segmentnum 1, group 1 = 0-11, group 2 = 12-32, group 3 = 33 - 66).

Comment: Actually, all good now! Just wrapped it with an if clause. =IF(MATCH([@vol], INDEX(table2[group 1]:table2[group 4], MATCH([@segmentnum], table2[segmentnum], 0),0))=4,3,MATCH([@vol], INDEX(table2[group 1]:table2[group 4], MATCH([@segmentnum], table2[segmentnum], 0),0)))

Thank you so much!